# Heroku Python/Django applications all simultaneously developed ImportError

Tags: python, django, heroku, importerror

Today all my Python/Django applications on Heroku stopped working.

The logs for all of them show the same issue.  When trying to restart/build, the error log is as shown below.

I have tried rebuilding the projects in a new local virtual environment, and they work fine locally.  However, when pushing them to Heroku, they encounter this ImportError and refuse to deploy.

Similarly, when I try to restart the existing applications, I see the same error logged prior to the instance crashing.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Error log:

```
2014-06-03T22:30:05.293788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509350+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509438+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "bluewaterads/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509536+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.core.management import execute_manager
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509589+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509644+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError, handle_default_options
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 16, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509707+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509727+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 2, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509796+00:00 app[web.1]:     import urllib
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509824+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509869+00:00 app[web.1]:     import socket
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509886+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 47, in <module>
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509919+00:00 app[web.1]:     import _socket
2014-06-03T22:30:11.509954+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: /app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so: undefined symbol: _PyInt_AsInt
2014-06-03T22:30:13.014774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-03T22:30:10.241602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python bluewaterads/manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:33709 -w 4`
2014-06-03T22:30:13.015823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.4.1
Mezzanine==1.2.4.1
Pillow==1.7.7
South==0.7.6
bleach==1.1.5
boto==2.5.2
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-appconf==0.5
django-compressor==1.2
django-s3-storages-utils==0.1.0
django-storages==1.1.5
filebrowser-safe==0.2.11
grappelli-safe==0.2.9
gunicorn==0.14.6
html5lib==0.95
psycopg2==2.4.5
pytz==2012d
```

Procfile:

```
web: python bluewaterads/manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `runtime.txt` with `python-2.7.7` to your project root and redeploy.

Heroku has just updated the runtime to python-2.7.7. This article was updated yesterday:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

[EDITED]: This forces Heroku to rebuild the virtualenv from scratch. You can specify any runtime.

Comment: Confirming that this fixes the problem, without buildpack set, on an app that broke out of nowhere.  I used `python-2.7.4` instead, so it may just be having *any* runtime set fixes it.

Comment: having this problem as well——as it turns out, including a runtime forces heroku to rebuild the virtualenv, which might provide a clue as to why it's fixing the issue for some. article here is germane: http://sloblog.io/+django/a-ACIZVQNHY/pillow-and-pil-and-heroku-and-runtime-dot-txt

Answer (score 3):

When deploying your application, if at runtime the updated python-2.7.7 is not being used.

Try purging the repo cache.

Install this: 
`heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git`

Then run this command:
`heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname`

Then deploy your application.

More info here:
[Heroku-repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the default Python buildpack? Heroku is in the process of updating the Stack image, and especially if you're not using a current buildpack, there may be incompatibilities.

To see if you're using a default buildpack, run

```
$ heroku config | grep BUILDPACK_URL
```

Please contact Heroku support if you think this might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to my heroku app, and after trying a million things I ended up fixing it by upgrading all of my packages including django, adding the wsgi.py file according to the django/heroku tutorial, and changing my procfile to this:

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi --pythonpath app --log-file -
```

The pythonpath setting is important because I had a ton of import errors and internal server errors because gunicorn no longer had the right path to my app.